# Rerouting to different method in same controller with POST

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have 2 index methods in a controller, one get to load the page initially and one post to accept form submit and reload the same view based on the submitted data.

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        loads page with viewmodel containing a searchobject that is submitted with a form on the page
    }

    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(SearchModel Model)
    {
        takes form submit and reloads page based on search results
        return View(Model);
    }
```

I also have an Add view/method in the same controller. What I'm wanting to do is when the add function is successful, I'd like to call the POST version of the index and pass it the id of the item that was just added.

here's what I have so far:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Add(AddModel addmodel)
    {
        do stuff

        var status = client.Add(dto);

        if (!status)
        {
            return View(AddModel);
        }
        SearchModel = new SearchModel();
        SearchModel.ID= addmodel.ID;
        return Index(search, null);
    }
```

It enters the POST index method but after it leaves that method it goes back to the add and tries to load the add page with the search viewmodel and obviously throws an exception.

Any ideas what my options are to do something like this?

Comment: Do you want user to see `Add` url in address bar after post or `Index`? In your case, I think, user sees `Add` url but with index's content. Try `RedirectToAction` instead, but you can't use POST.

Answer (score 0):

By default `View(Model)` uses name of current action (the one routed to - `Add` in your case, not the current method name - `Index`).

Fix: specify view name explicitly:

```
public ActionResult Index(SearchModel Model)
{
    takes form submit and reloads page based on search results
    return View("Index", Model);
}
```